# Grails with Criteria

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I want to use NVL Function in Grails Criteria for orderBy clause. How shall I used? I have tried multiple approach. Can anybody help me out ?

SQL Query to converted into Grails Criteria : 
Select * forom Domain_Table order by NVL(field1,field2) ASC

Tried Approach 1:

```
Domain.createCriteria().list(max:10,offset:10){
   order(field1,'ASC')
   order(field2,'ASC')
}
```

Working properly, But Generating SQL Query like

```
Select * forom Domain_Table order by field1 ASC,field2 ASC
```

which is not satisfying my requirement

Approach 2 :

```
 Domain.createCriteria().list(max:10,offset:10){
       order(nvl(field1,field2),'ASC')
    }
```

Error : Nvl Not a property of domain class

Approach 3 :

```
Domain.createCriteria().list(max:10,offset:10){
   projections{
  addProjectionToList(Projections.sqlProjection("nvl(field1,field2) as description", ['description'] as String[], [Hibernate.STRING] as Type[]), 'description'))
           order('description,'ASC')
        }
```

Problem : 
I am getting the record based on the exact order . But, Again I am hitting database with description to get the Domain Which I don't want. 
One more option is there, I can put property(name,alias) which I'll get in response. But, I need the entire domain to be queried.

### Please help me out.

Comment: Have you tried an HQL query? I'm not sure if it handles NVL, but it would be something like this: `Domain.executeQuery('select d from Domain as d order by NVL(d.field1, d.field2)`. Unlike criteria query projections, with HQL you can _project_ the root entity (Domain).

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa :  I can use HQL and can able to perform. But, I have a constraints not to use HQL. I need to use only Criteria...

Answer (score 2):

You can use @Formula for an artificial field on Entity (let's name it `nvl`) and then use it in ordering.

Or you can use custom implementation of Order

```
public class OrderBySqlFormula extends Order {
    private String sqlFormula;

    /**
     * Constructor for Order.
     * @param sqlFormula an SQL formula that will be appended to the resulting SQL query
     */
    protected OrderBySqlFormula(String sqlFormula) {
        super(sqlFormula, true);
        this.sqlFormula = sqlFormula;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return sqlFormula;
    }

    public String toSqlString(Criteria criteria, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery) throws HibernateException {
        return sqlFormula;
    }

    /**
     * Custom order
     *
     * @param sqlFormula an SQL formula that will be appended to the resulting SQL query
     * @return Order
     */
    public static Order sqlFormula(String sqlFormula) {
        return new OrderBySqlFormula(sqlFormula);
    }
}
```

and use `criteria.addOrder(OrderBySqlFormula.sqlFormula("(a + b) desc"));`

from here

http://blog.tremend.ro/2008/06/10/how-to-order-by-a-custom-sql-formulaexpression-when-using-hibernate-criteria-api/

Comment: This is one of the very good approach. Can you suggest some other approach ? @StanislavL

Answer (score 1):

Since you must to use a criteria, without modifying the domain class your third approach is the closest to a solution.

You can add the domain class `id` to the projections, grab all of the IDs, and finally, call `Domain.getAll()` to return the instances. You'll need two queries, but the second one uses the primary key, so it'll run as fast as possible.

```
def ids = Domain.createCriteria().list(max:10,offset:10){
   projections{
      property('id')
      sqlProjection("nvl(field1,field2) as description", 'description', Hibernate.STRING)           
   }
   order('description','ASC')
}*.getAt(0) // Only selects the first column: the ID.

def instances = Domain.getAll(ids)
```

Comment: Agree...
But, As I mentioned , It needs one more DB Call which cost me more... ?